# How can Javascript returns a string formatted as a gcode co-ordinate

Tags: javascript, g-code

```
function gcodeXY(source){
    var s = source;
    var f = s.split(",");
    var r = f.join(" ");
    //perhaps split source
    return r;
}
```

How can Javascript returns a string formatted as a gcode co-ordinate?
The picture is the desired input and output, and my current output. So I want to know how I should add X and Y.

[image]

Comment: why would you *expect* the letters X and Y? where would they come from? you need to put them in yourself ... `r=\`X${s[0]} Y${s[1]}\`` for example

Comment: The ultimate goal is to parse an svg file with multiple paths and produce valid gcode.

Comment: well, now you know how

Answer (score 1):

`f` is an array with 2 elements. You can destructure it and then add X and Y

```js
function gcodeXY(source){
    var [xVal, yVal] = source.split(",");
    return `X${xVal} Y${yVal}`
}

console.log(gcodeXY("1,2"))
```